# Is the new Altbeacon Lib. v2.16.2 supporting Android "O" Scannable API?

Tags: altbeacon

In Android  API level 26, "setScannable" is added.

"setScannable" Added in API level 26
public AdvertisingSetParameters.Builder setScannable (boolean scannable)

Set whether the advertisement type should be scannable. Legacy advertisements can be both connectable and scannable. Non-legacy advertisements can be only scannable or only connectable.

I am creating a beacon and want to set it non-scannable mode.

Just wondering if the latest Altbeacon Lib. v2.16.2 support this setting? If not, is there a way to use Android API and Altbeacon Lib. together to set a beacon's advertising parameters?

Thanks!

Tried Altbeacon Lib. v2.15.2, it seems that Android API level 26 is not support, which means that "setScannable" is not available.

```
String id1 = "3b710c27-acf7-4225-8753-4aca354f5bec";    // UUID
String id2 = "1";
String id3 = "2";
Beacon beacon = new Beacon.Builder()
            .setId1(id1)
            .setId2(id2)
            .setId3(id3)
            .setManufacturer(0x01F1)
            .setTxPower(iTxPower)
            .setDataFields(Arrays.asList(new Long[] {0l}))
            .build();
BeaconParser beaconParser = new BeaconParser().                
setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=beac,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25");
BeaconTransmitter beaconTransmitter = new 
BeaconTransmitter(getApplicationContext(), beaconParser);
beaconTransmitter.startAdvertising(beacon);
...
```

I would hope Altbeacon Lib. v2.16.2 could support Android API Level 26 so that "setScannable" is supported.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such configuration ability in the 2.16.2 version of the library.  It is logged as a feature request here:

https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/issues/813

This would not be difficult to add if you would like to work on that feature request.  Please comment on that linked page above, if so, and I can give you guidance on what to do.